# Array formulas: nested ifs and same row calculation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2013, array-formulas

[image: Image for reference here]

There are 2 inputs: `A1` and `B1`.

In column D, there are many types of objects A.
In column B, there are many types of objects B.

Here's what the formula is supposed to do:
If (D2 is 'A1' and G2 is 'B1') then, if (E2 is bigger than F2), subtract E2 and F2 (5 - 4, in this example), otherwise subtract F2 to E2 (like what happens in line 12).
If there is no match, don't do anything and just skip the row.

I would like to do this as an array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>), so it would sum everything in the end.

In this example, the output would be -1, because sum(and(5-4)(2-4)) .

So far, I have the following:

```
{=SUM(IF((D2:D12="A1")+(G2:G12="B1");E2:E12-F2:F12;0))}
```

But it doesn't work properly as I'm not sure how Excel reads the subtraction part. I want to be able to subtract the values for the row where the combination was found.

Comment: Why is it `2-4`?  _"if(E2 is bigger than F2), subtract E2 and F2 (5 - 4, in this example), otherwise subtract F2 to E2"_ but in this case E (4) IS bigger than F (2) so wouldn't you do 4-2?

Comment: That is correct. I forgot to retake the screenshot when uploading.Thank you for noticing the typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is to have Column E subtracted by Column F for all matches then consider the following Array Formula:

```
=SUM((D2:D12=$B$2)*(G2:G12=$B$3)*(E2:E12-F2:F12))
```

(This can be updated with extra checks on what to subtract if needed)

This will `SUM` all of the subtractions (Column E) - (Column F) that contain a match to your inputs.

Here is the breakdown:

`D2:D12=$B$2` and `G2:G12=$B$3` will produce arrays containing 1's for a match and 0's for non-match:

```
{A1,A2,A3, -,A1, -, -,A4,A5,A1,A1}  {B1, -,B1, -,B4, -, -,B6,B5,B2,B1}
 V           V              V  V     V     V                       V
{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 }  {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 }
```

`E2:E12-F2:F12` will result in a 3rd array consisting of the subtracted values:

```
 {5, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 7, 3, 9, 7, 4}
-{4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 9, 6, 7, 8, 2}
={1, 2,-1,-4,-3,-2,-2,-3, 2,-1, 2}
```

Multiplying all of them will result like so:

```
 {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}
x{1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
x{1, 2,-1,-4,-3,-2,-2,-3, 2,-1, 2}
={1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}
```

Then of course `SUM` will do it's job:

```
SUM({1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}) = 3
```

Comment: Very detailed answer and explanation! Thank you very much

Comment: Any idea why '{=MEDIAN(($B$46:$B$1930=$B4)*($D$46:$D$1930-$F$46:$F$1930))}' returns a 0 result, while sum or max work just fine? (the median isn't really 0). It shouldn't be any different, right?

Comment: @ichimok I don't believe `MEDIAN` can take array's directly.  But you can use an IF statement to take in the array and pass it to `MEDIAN` like:  `=MEDIAN(IF($B$46:$B$1930=$B4,$D$46:$D$1930-$F$46:$F$1930))}`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you are asking for correctly then yours answer would be:

```
=SUM((D2:D12="A1")*(G2:G12="B1")*ABS(E2:E12-F2:F12))
```

Remember that `TRUE` to Excel is the same thing as nubmer 1 and `FALSE` is 0.

So if any in my formula any row that has either D or G column not matching will be multiplied by 0.

Also your rule about E and F columns sounds to me like 
Subtract the smaller from bigger number
this is same as:

```
|4-5|=1
```

Or in Excel formula notation:

```
ABS(4-5)
```

Comment: Absolute is not a solution, as I'd need to sum the negative values and not make them positive. Still, thanks for the input, as the rest works great!